# OnMouseOver using an <asp:image runat=

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net

I have an image using a normal asp image tag, which uses ImageURL as such:

```
 <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/TeamImages/Asset 4.png"  runat="server" ID="aks" />
```

all the examples i have seen use src and imagebuttons instead, using vb.net is there a way to change the url of the image when hovered over the image

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put some javascript to onmouseover html attribute. You can declare it in you .aspx markup, or you can do it in codebehind:

```
aks.Attributes("onmouseover") = "javascript: this.src='/newimage.png';"
```

Comment: Doing it in the codebehind, and inline it does change the image but doesnt show the imge .. it shows an image icon like the image hasnt loaded

Comment: Does the new image really exists on the new path? It will propaby not. There will be some delay when loading the image for the first time (you can avoid it by joining images to one and manipulating it's position by CSS class or you can preload the image using javascript)